# Python based - pulling data in tables

Tags: python, api, datatables

I am new to programming and looking for help.

I am pulling soccer data from API-football and running it in jupyter notebook to test - data all coming back fine.

How do I get the data into tables now in jupyter notebook for testing purposes - I have attached pic.

Any help guys greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ants[enter image description here][1]

Comment: instead of adding a picture, add the code itself and the result of its run

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([response.json])
```

I am not sure.